# Insert values in second row of csv file, pertaining the first line in ksh script

Tags: awk

I am trying to insert values to the second row of a csv file. Firstly, I am inserting the header to the file as:

```
echo 'FILE_TYPE,PERCENT_SPACE_USED,DB_NAME,THRESHOLD' > output.csv
```

Secondly I want to insert value under each column. First two of which I have in a text file (output.txt) and 3rd and 4th are in variables.

```
awk -F"," -v DB="ABCDE",THRESH="75" 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR>2{$1=$1+DB+THRESH} {print $0}NR!=1' output.txt > output.csv
```

But what I am getting is that my header is overwritten and the output of text file in 2 lines as:

```
        ARCHIVED LOG        ,               .09                                                             
        ARCHIVED LOG        ,               .09
```

Below is how my input file (output.txt looks like):

```
        ARCHIVED LOG        ,               .09
```

Comment: Could you please add sample of your Input_file with code tags in your question too?

Comment: I have edited the question to include input file

Comment: Instead of the `echo`, write your header in the `BEGIN` block of the awk.

Comment: No, not at all clear, please add 3 simple things in your posts, 1- sample of Input_file, 2- sample of output_file 3- whatever you tried to solve this problem in your post too.

Comment: Also note (from the manual): _The -v option can only set one variable, but it can be used more than once, setting another variable each time, like this: ‘awk -v foo=1 -v bar=2 …’._

Comment: Also, the `+` sign is just for arithmetic, (it won't concatenate strings like in some languages).  Try instead `$1=$1 OFS DB OFS THRESH`.

Comment: The fact that your code contains `NR>2` and `NR!=1` implies that there's more to your input file than you're showing. Can you show at least the first five or so lines of input to make it more clear what you have?

Comment: @jas, if you need feel free to edit my code/solution too sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to add something like header before your output shown then following may help you, this is why `awk` have `BEGIN` section where we could do stuff before reading an Input_file eg-->

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "FILE_TYPE,PERCENT_SPACE_USED,DB_NAME,THRESHOLD"} ...... your_code' Input_file
```

Comment: I had to make some edits in my code but the idea to get header print in awk did the trick. Thanks @jas and RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1):

you can also use sed for this purpose, to insert a line on top of a file just do a:

```
sed -i.bak '1s/^/\"FILE_TYPE,PERCENT_SPACE_USED,DB_NAME,THRESHOLD\"\n/g' file
```

This will insert a line on top of the file defined by `1s` , `2s` will insert it in second line and so on.

Comment: Always try to suggest `i.bak` option so that it will take backup of Original Input_file and make a new copy of Input_file with changes, keep it up.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you for the suggestion, made required edits, always a learning experience with you :)